# How to set the Bibliography title for BibTex in Pandoc

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, pandoc

I currently render my thesis with Markdown files as source, and want to generate a PDF output. I use the following command for that:

```
pandoc --template template.latex --standalone --chapters \
       -V linestretch=1.5 --toc --number-sections --bibliography sources.bib \
          00_title.md 01_introduction.md \
          02_state-of-the-art.md 03_implementation.md 04_discussion.md \
          05_conclusion.md \
       -o thesis.pdf
```

I would like to also set the bibliography title, since it currently doesn't appear, and the sources are just attached right after the last sentence.

I have already tried to add `-V biblio-title=Bibliography`, because it seems like this is the variable used in the LaTeX template. It didn't fail, but it seems to just ignore this value.

So how can the title of the bibliography be correctly set?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update:** Since the original answer in 2015 the command line interface of pandoc has changed, e.g. the built-in mechanism needs the option `--citeproc` and `-S`/`--smart` is an [extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-smart) in recent versions. I changed the the answer to reflect this. The most up-to-date documentation can, of course, be found in the [manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations).

### Short answer

- For the built-in mechanism use: `--citeproc -M reference-section-title=Whatever` (see Art's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/642093/29873))
- For biblatex/natbib use: `--biblatex` or `--natbib` and `-V biblio-title=Whatever`

### Long answer

If you are producing LaTeX output with pandoc you have three options for the bibliography: (1.) The built-in mechanism `citeproc`, (2.) `natbib`, or (3.)`biblatex`.

#### 1. Buit-in mechanism

The built-in mechanism (`citeproc`) writes the bibliographic information without heading at the end of the file. Just end your document with a heading of your choosing:

test.bib:

```
@article{doe1905,
 author={Doe, John},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year={1905},
}
```

test.md:

```
# Test

This is a test [@doe1905].

# Bibliography
```

**Command:** `pandoc --citeproc --bibliography=test.bib -o test.pdf test.md`

[image]

**Changing the title of the bibliography:** With `citeproc` you can either give the last section, at the very end of the document, the title you want, or you could set the name with the option `-M reference-section-title=Whatever`: `pandoc --citeproc --bibliography=test.bib -M reference-section-title=Whatever -o test.pdf test.md`

This has the advantage, that it will produce consistent output also for other formats like Microsoft Word (.docx) or Open/Libre Office (.odt).

#### 2. Natbib

Use `natbib` to produce a .tex file and compile it afterwards with `latexmk`, `arara` or whatever tool you like:

**Command:** `pandoc --standalone --natbib --bibliography=test.bib -o test.tex test.md && latexmk test.tex`

[image]

**Changing the title of the bibliography:** `pandoc --standalone --natbib --bibliography=test.bib -V biblio-title=Whatever -o test.tex test.md && latexmk test.tex` will give you:

[image]

#### 3. Biblatex

Use `biblatex` to produce a .tex file and compile it afterwards with `latexmk`, `arara` or whatever tool you like:

**Command:** `pandoc --standalone --biblatex --bibliography=test.bib -o test.tex test.md && latexmk test.tex`

[image]

**Changing the title of the bibliography:** `pandoc --standalone --biblatex --bibliography=test.bib -V biblio-title=Whatever -o test.tex test.md && latexmk test.tex` will produce:

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of specifying the `-s` flag twice?

Comment: @user32882 — One is standalone, the other used to be smart, but has been moved to reader and/or writer options in more recent versions of pandoc

Comment: What does `-S` actually do?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `citeproc`, you can put in `reference-section-title` in the metadata.

https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-citeproc/blob/master/man/pandoc-citeproc.1.md

```
pandoc --template template.latex --standalone --chapters \
       -V linestretch=1.5 --toc --number-sections --bibliography sources.bib \
       -M reference-section-title=References \
          00_title.md 01_introduction.md \
          02_state-of-the-art.md 03_implementation.md 04_discussion.md \
          05_conclusion.md \
       -o thesis.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you. Would be helpful, if you could add a screenshot showing relevant results from your approach. Thanks

Comment: @MS-SPO Not sure as I do not have the source files mentioned. But it looks exactly like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC5X0.png produced in the answer above.